# Force template to 'listen' to the changes in modal: Angular2

Tags: angular

I have an array property in one of my component which is being rendered in the template, like the following:

```
 <div *ngIf="results && results.length > 0">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th (click)="someFunction()"><span>Column1</span>
            </th>
            <th (click)="someFunction2()"><span>Column2 </span>
            </th>
            <th (click)="someFunction3()"><span>Column3</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let result of results">
            <td>{{ result.property1) }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.property2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.property3 }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

The above is simple and straightforward. Now, the results property in the template receives some data from the api, and also the result property is being saved in the sessionStorage. So whnever I navigate to any other page and come back, I see the last received data from the API in results property. But, whenever I'm making another API call again and overwriting the stuff in results property, the template still shows the old data. This behavior is weird to me because I'm using string interpolation. So is there a way to force the template to get the latest changes from the template?

Comment: We can't find the bug in your code if you don't post your code.

Comment: @JBNizet, can I give you the link of a google sheet where I have the components?

Comment: No. Post he relevant code in the question itself. A link to a plnkr reproducing the problem would be nice, too.